# Spliterator causing duplicate key exception while for loop does not

Tags: java, cassandra, java-8, java-stream

I'm using Java 8 streams.

When I use a spliterator to add to my map, I get duplicate key exception, but using standard for loop does not throw an exception.

```
// This works
Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Row row : result.result()) {
    myMap.put(row.get(0, Integer.class), null);
}

// This throws exception
myMap = StreamSupport.stream(result.result().spliterator(), true)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(row -> row.get(0, Integer.class), row -> ""));
```

If it makes any difference, result is a Cassandra resultset and row is a Cassandra row.

Comment: example problem data?

Comment: You would be better creating an [MCVE] which would likely eliminate cassandra from the problem and be more general and therefore more useful to future visitors of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a standard for loop, if you put a key that is already present in the `Map`, the old value is replaced by the new value.

The 2 arguments `toMap` collector, on the other hand, throws an exception if multiple values are mapped to the same key.

To avoid that, you need to supply a merge function in order to handle such collisions.

For example:

```
myMap = 
    StreamSupport.stream(result.result().spliterator(), true)
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(row -> row.get(0, Integer.class), 
                                           row -> "",
                                           (v1,v2) -> v2));
```

This will take one of the values and ignore the other in case of collisions. You can choose other merge functions, such as appending the two values:

```
(v1,v2) -> v1 + ", " + v2
```

As Eugene commented, results are merged into the `Map` in encounter order.

Comment: also.. looking that there is a `Row` there, I assume some SQL... and if the underlying result is not ordered (usually isn't) this (as well as the for loop) might return different results from run to run. But I guess OP is aware of that

Comment: It's a Cassandra resultset. The keys are sorted by the date the where added to Cassandra table. So the values which are they keys for the map are NOT in numeric order 1,2,3,4... they can be 4, 1, 3, 2 So it's ok